# Issue with authentication using Git Kraken and self hosted Gitlab

Tags: gitlab, gitkraken, gitlab-ce

so I have a self-hosted Gitlab, I use Git kraken pro and git for windows to enable the LFS component.

I'm having the issue where when I push to my repository git kraken asks for authentication. (Username and password.) How ever I have no such issue when I pull the data, it will just do the job. And the same is for the LFS, I can pull but not push the data without a password.

Here is the set up:

I have not been successful in setting up the ssh keys at this point as it refuses to use them and I'm still trying to work that issue out.
I have pressed the "remember me" option for the pop up and that doesn't seem to work
I have set up the access token and that all works.
The GitLab ce is installed on a Linux OS and I am connecting to it via 4 windows PC's using git kraken (all on pro licenses).

Git lab CE is updated to the latest version and same for git Kraken

Obviously, the preferred method of connection to the git is SSH but it refuses to work. I have tried the git kraken's version of ssh and manually creating and installing the keys using cmd line.
When I enter the U/P to push the data it only works for that single push even if I don't restart git lab. Every single time I need to place a user name and password and this is tiresome.

What I'm asking is, how can I fix this? This is my first full-fledged self-hosted git, and I've learned things on the fly, I do have normal git experience but the set up for the self-hosted is a lot more involved compared to just using git itself.

The reason I am self-hosting is, cost. My repos are GB in size and I have many. So, I need to have my own set up to avoid having those kinds of costs.

How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 1):

> When I enter the U/P to push the data it only works for that single push even if I don't restart git lab. Every single time I need to place a user name and password and this is tiresome.

Double-check if your GitKraken is actually using an SSH URL (`git@yourServer:user/repo`), as a username/password should only work for HTTMS URL (`https://yourServer/user/repo`)

Check the SSH port is reachable from your windows:

```
curl -v telnet://yourServer:22
```

If it does not connect, double-check your [Omnibus installation on Linux](https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/), making sure the SSH daemon is started and active, using the [right `sshd_config`](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/raw/master/docker/assets/sshd_config).

---

The [OP Maize](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14152246/maize) adds in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73264630/issue-with-authentication-using-git-kraken-and-self-hosted-gitlab#comment129475057_73274323):

> A complete reinstall and removal of setting in GitKraken solved the issue.
> Previous uninstalled seems to of kept the settings, so when I removed those, it sorted itself out.

Comment: Thank you i will look into that tonight and report back what the results are

Comment: Okay so after checking and changing settings, A complete reinstall and removal of setting in git kraken solved the issue, previous uninstalled seems to of kept the settings so when i removed those, it sorted it self out, Thank you for tyhe solutions, i would not of checked that if those were not mentioned.

Comment: @Maize Great, well done! I have included your conclusion in the answer for more visibility.